# Displaying JQuery Mobile icons beside each others above image

Tags: css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I'm trying to display jquery mobile icons beside each other on a ribbon above image but the icons appear on the same place over each other.

I tried to give them a relative position and set a margin left for each one of them but did not work too like the following

```
<div style='position: relative; margin-left:-60px'><span class='ui- btn-icon-notext ui-icon-eye'  /></div>
```

Here is my code https://jsitor.com/Cucuyhhsq

I expect the icons will appear like the following image:

[image: icons]

Comment: https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/controlgroup/#Controlgrouphorizontal

Comment: No that won't work.